# Reset scroll SwiftUI List to top when reloaded with new data / MacOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a List whose contents can be updated. If the contents are changed after the list has been scrolled down screen, the updated List does not reset to the top.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyData {
    let a: [String]
    let b: [String]
    
    init() {
        var pa = [String]()
        var pb = [String]()
        
        for i in 0...100 {
            pa.append("A: \(i)")
            pb.append("B: \(i)")
        }
        
        self.a = pa
        self.b = pb
    }
}

struct ListNotResetingToTop: View {
    let data = MyData()
    @State var showA = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Switch") { showA.toggle() }
            List(showA ? data.a : data.b, id: \.self) { value in
                Text(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried wrapping the List in a ScrollReader, but this did not work either:

```
struct ListNotResetingToTop: View {
    let data = MyData()
    @State var showA = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Switch") { showA.toggle() }
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List(showA ? data.a : data.b, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text(value)
                }.onChange(of: showA) { _ in
                    proxy.scrollTo(showA ? data.a.first : data.b.first)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need something like

```
    VStack {
        Button("Switch") { showA.toggle() }

        List(showA ? data.a : data.b, id: \.self) { value in
            Text(value)
        }.id(showA)         // just make id depend on modified data

    }
```